# MSTest 2.0 DataTestMethod swaping parameters order

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am a bit new to C# and MSTest in general, I am trying to do a parameterized Unit Test using DynamicData property it would seem that the parameters are being swap during runtime here a snippet of my test:

```
     [TestClass]
     public class SampleTest
     {
         private TestContext testContextInstance;

         public TestContext TestContext
         {
            get { return testContextInstance; }
            set { testContextInstance = value; }
         }
         private static IEnumerable<object[]> ReusableTestData =>
                        new List<object[]> {
                        new object[] { 1, 2, 3 },
                        new object[] { 4, 5, 6 }
                };
         [DataTestMethod]
         [DynamicData(nameof(ReusableTestData))]
         public void Test1(int param1, int param2, int param3 )
         {
            TestContext.WriteLine($"{param1} {param2} {param3}");
         }
```

On the console, in the first test I get:

> 1 2 3

On the second test I get:

> 6 5 4

Am I missing some configuration here? or Is it maybe a known issue regarding MSTest and their parameterized tests?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that output.  Its [`1 2 3` and `4 5 6` using your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4oJK.png) for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the problem came because I updated TestFramework library to V2.2.4.
By downgrading to V2.0.0 that library I can compile again.